# Comma before the word "who"?

Tags: punctuation

Why do we need comma in the following sentence?

> This is Gabriel, who I told you about.

Is it correct without comma?

Answer (score 3):

You need a comma to separate/set off the "This is Gabriel" with the **non-essential relative clause** "who I told you about".

This is non-restrictive because you the information in it is not vital in specifying what something is.

For an essential relative clause, see this:

> The children **who skateboard in the street** are especially noisy in the early evening.

You cannot get rid of the relative clause here because it is essential to defining which specific children, so no commas.

Meanwhile:

> This is Gabriel, **who I told you about.**

You can get rid of the relative clause here because it is not essential to defining what Gabriel is, so commas you go.

Source: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm

Comment: I wonder if we can say "This is **the** Gabriel who I told you about" (to indicate that this is a particular Gabriel).

Comment: Then that would have an essential relative clause do define which Gabriel it is! The OP's sentence seems to **introduce a guy named Gabriel**, which the OP **brings up as a person that he told the listener about beforehand**. While your sentence means that "this guy is the **correct particular Gabriel that I was talking about**".

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you consider it as a **non-defining** or **defining** relative clause.

The latter adds vital information about the noun, so no comma is required.
The former adds extra information.

> *This is Gabriel, who I told you about, an engineer.* (**non-defining.**)
>   *This is Gabriel who is an engineer.* (**defining.**)